# formula and matrix over two columns in amcs style

Tags: math-mode, two-column

I have a very simple problem with formulas and large matrices in a two column environment.I also did a search on the site but the correct answer to my problem was not in the other questions and answers found on the site.
I have attached the written text. How do I solve the problem of the formula or matrix falling on the text of the next column? What is your solution?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 Heretofore various and fascinating articles and books on numerical methods  
\begin{eqnarray}\label{Main}
\min\hspace{0.5cm} J&=&\frac{1}{2}x^T(t_f)Sx(t_f)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t_f}\{ 
 x^T(t)Qx(t)+u^T(t)Ru(t)\}dt\\
 s.t\ \ \ \ \ \ {\dot x}(t)&=&A_1x(t)+ A_2x(t-\tau)+B_1u(t)+B_2u(t-\tau),\ \  0\leq t \leq L,\\
     x(0)&=&x_0,\\
   x(t)&=&\theta(t), \ \    -\tau \leq t<0,\\
u(t)&=&\psi (t),\ \ -\tau \leq t<0,
\end{eqnarray}
 So we can have following matrix
\begin{align*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
{\tilde A}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c|ccc}
a_0 &      \frac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2} &   \frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} &  a_{-3} &   \frac{a_{-2}-a_2}{2} &  
\frac{a_{-1}-a_1}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2} & a_0   &    \frac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}+a_1-a_3}{2} & a_{-2} & \frac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}- 
a_1+a_3}{2} &  0 & \frac{a_{1}-a_{-1}}{2} \\
 \frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} &  \frac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}+a_1-a_3}{2} & \frac{a_{-2}+2a_0-a_2}{2} & a_{-1} &  
\frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2}&  \frac{a_{-3}-a_{-1}+a_1+a_3}{2} &  \frac{a_{2}-a_{-2}}{2} \\ \hline
 a_{-3} & a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1 & a_2&  a_{3}\\ \hline
\frac{a_{-2}-a_2}{2} & \frac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}-a_1+a_3}{2} & \frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & a_1& \frac{a_2+2a_0- 
a_{-2}}{2}& \frac{a_3+a_{-1}+a_1-a_{-3}}{2} &  \frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2}\\
\frac{a_{-1}-a_1}{2} & 0 &\frac{a_{-3}-a_{-1}+a_1+a_3}{2} & a_2& \frac{a_{3}+a_1+a_{-1}-a_{-3}}{2} & 
a_0&  \frac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2}\\
0&  \frac{a_{1}-a_{-1}}{2} & \frac{a_{2}-a_{-2}}{2}& a_3&  \frac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & \frac{a_{-1}+a_1} 
{2} &a_0
        \end{array}
\right).
\end{align*}
 The Fourier trigonometric functions are the very most straightforward example of an orthogonal 
 system of eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint boundary value problem. The key to the efficacy of 
 Fourier series rests on the orthogonality properties of the trigonometric functions, which is a 
 direct consequence of their status as eigenfunctions of the most basic self-adjoint boundary value 
 problem. In this manner, the Fourier series can also be viewed as a function space version of the 
 finite-dimensional spectral theory of symmetric matrices and orthogonal eigenvector bases. The main 
 problem is that we must deal with infinite series rather than finite sums; therefore, convergence 
 subject that does not appear in the finite-dimensional situation, become of paramount importance.\\
 The aim of present paper is to use the Hartley series to solve the optimal quadratic time- 
 independent delay optimal control problem
 The Fourier trigonometric functions are the very most straightforward example of an orthogonal 
 system of eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint boundary value problem. The key to the efficacy of 
 Fourier series rests on the orthogonality properties of the trigonometric functions, which is a 
 direct consequence of their status as eigenfunctions of the most basic self-adjoint boundary value 
 problem. In this manner, the Fourier series can also be viewed as a function space version of the 
 finite-dimensional spectral theory of symmetric matrices and orthogonal eigenvector bases. The main 
 problem is that we must deal with infinite series rather than finite sums; therefore, convergence 
 subject that does not appear in the finite-dimensional situation, become of paramount importance.\\
 The aim of present paper is to use the Hartley series to solve the optimal quadratic time- 
 independent delay optimal control problem\\

 \end{document}
```

here is the output:
[image]

Comment: You might try inserting your maths in  a `strip` environment (from the `cuted` package), which temporarily leaves the two-column mode.

Comment: ِdear Bernard; 
Unfortunately, this command eliminate a part of text. how can i solve this?

Comment: I've just posted  a solution for your problem. I hope it's OK for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution consists in adding the minimisation problem in the strip environment. Anyway, the corresponding equation are too wide to fit in a single column. Here a working code, which hopefully corresponds to what you want. I took the liberty to replace the `eqnarray` environment, which has a bad spacing, with one of the environments of the `optidef` package. The equation and the constraints are numbered as subequations, not as independent equations, and the layout is done automatically. I also improved the matrix with the medium-sized fractions from the `nccmath` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef, nccmath}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}
 Heretofore various and fascinating articles and books on numerical methods

 \begin{strip}
 \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
 \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{mini!}|s|
  {} {J=\frac{1}{2}x^T(t_f)Sx(t_f)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t_f}\{
 x^T(t)Qx(t)+u^T(t)Ru(t)\}dt}{\label{Main1}}{}
 \addConstraint{\dot x(t)}{=A_1x(t)+ A_2x(t-\tau)+B_1u(t)+B_2u(t-\tau),\quad 0\leq t \leq L,}
  \addConstraint{x(0)}{=x_0,}
  \addConstraint{x(t)}{=\theta(t), \quad -\tau \leq t<0}
 \addConstraint{u(t)}{=\psi (t),\quad -\tau \leq t<0.}
\end{mini!}
 \intertext{So we can have following matrix}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
{\tilde A}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c|ccc}
a_0 & \mfrac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & a_{-3} & \mfrac{a_{-2}-a_2}{2} &
\mfrac{a_{-1}-a_1}{2} & 0 \\
 \mfrac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2} & a_0 & \mfrac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}+a_1-a_3}{2} & a_{-2} & \mfrac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}-
a_1+a_3}{2} & 0 & \mfrac{a_{1}-a_{-1}}{2} \\
 \mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}+a_1-a_3}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-2}+2a_0-a_2}{2} & a_{-1} &
\mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2}& \mfrac{a_{-3}-a_{-1}+a_1+a_3}{2} & \mfrac{a_{2}-a_{-2}}{2} \\[1ex] \hline
 a_{-3} & a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1 & a_2& a_{3}\\ \hline
\mfrac{a_{-2}-a_2}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-3}+a_{-1}-a_1+a_3}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & a_1& \mfrac{a_2+2a_0-
a_{-2}}{2}& \mfrac{a_3+a_{-1}+a_1-a_{-3}}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2}\\
\mfrac{a_{-1}-a_1}{2} & 0 &\mfrac{a_{-3}-a_{-1}+a_1+a_3}{2} & a_2& \mfrac{a_{3}+a_1+a_{-1}-a_{-3}}{2} &
a_0& \mfrac{a_{-1}+a_1}{2}\\
0 & \mfrac{a_{1}-a_{-1}}{2} & \mfrac{a_{2}-a_{-2}}{2}& a_3 & \mfrac{a_{-2}+a_2}{2} & \mfrac{a_{-1}+a_1}
{2} & a_0
        \end{array}
\right).
\end{gather*}
\end{strip}
 The Fourier trigonometric functions are the very most straightforward example of an orthogonal system of eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint boundary value problem. The key to the efficacy of Fourier series rests on the orthogonality properties of the trigonometric functions, which is a direct consequence of their status as eigenfunctions of the most basic self-adjoint boundary value problem. In this manner, the Fourier series can also be viewed as a function space version of the finite-dimensional spectral theory of symmetric matrices and orthogonal eigenvector bases. The main problem is that we must deal with infinite series rather than finite sums; therefore, convergence subject that does not appear in the finite-dimensional situation, become of paramount importance.

 The aim of present paper is to use the Hartley series to solve the optimal quadratic time-independent delay optimal control problem.

 The Fourier trigonometric functions are the very most straightforward example of an orthogonal system of eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint boundary value problem. The key to the efficacy of Fourier series rests on the orthogonality properties of the trigonometric functions, which is a direct consequence of their status as eigenfunctions of the most basic self-adjoint boundary value problem. In this manner, the Fourier series can also be viewed as a function space version of the finite-dimensional spectral theory of symmetric matrices and orthogonal eigenvector bases. The main problem is that we must deal with infinite series rather than finite sums; therefore, convergence subject that does not appear in the finite-dimensional situation, become of paramount importance.

 The aim of present paper is to use the Hartley series to solve the optimal quadratic time-independent delay optimal control problem.

 \end{document}
```

[image]